# Array is initializing more elements than told too

Tags: java, arrays

Java:

> int [] list = new int [7];
>
> System.out.print(list);

In the console it prints: [I@1f96302

Not only is it giving values other than ints, but it is giving more than I asked it too.

Comment: That isn't the array content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[l@1f96302` is the default way an Object is printed (that's what Object's `toString()` method returns for arrays). Try `System.out.print(Arrays.toString(list))` instead, which will display the elements of the array.

Comment: [I@1f96302 is the Java default way to print an object that has no toString() implementation. It is the internal runtime type and memory address: [ means Array, I means integer @ means 'now comes the mem address' and the memory address itself.